# R download.file downloading corrupted and smaller file

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a script to download a daily updated dataset. But the final file seems corrupted and is only 9~10kb while the original one is 95kb. Below is my code.

```
#Getting dataset from website daily

dir = getwd()
dash= "/"
date = Sys.Date()
date = gsub("-","",date)
filename = "CoronaDataSet"
extension = ".zip"

save = paste(dir,dash,date," - ",filename,extension, sep = "")
save
url = "https://www.kaggle.com/imdevskp/corona-virus-report/download"

download.file(url,save)
```

My console returns the following:

```
trying URL 'https://www.kaggle.com/imdevskp/corona-virus-report/download'
Content type 'text/html; charset=utf-8' length unknown
downloaded 8957 bytes
```

I also tried mode = "wb","a","ab". None downloaded the full size file.

Method = "auto","libcurl","curl" returns and invalid argument.

```
cannot open destfile 'C:/Users/Name/Documents/R/Course/Download file from url/20200323 - CoronaDataSet.zip', reason 'Invalid argument'
```

What may I be missing in my code? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can't really tell much, the link requires an account. It would help if you could make this relatively self-contained or at least publicly available data sample.

Comment: Thank you, I tried the same code on a no login required website and it worked. Maybe that was the problem. Now I'll try to solve how to login through r and download the file.